# How to prevent "@typescript-eslint/unbound method" errors on non-class TypeScript interfaces?

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

The code below doesn't use classes or `this`. How can I prevent typescript-eslint errors in function-only (no classes) code?  I know I can disable the rule globally, but the rule is useful for class code. I know I can disable it one line at a time, but that seems like a pain given how common it is to have callback functions defined in TS interfaces.  Is there another way?

Here's a simplified example of the problem:

```js
interface FooProps {
  bar(): void;
}

export function foo(props: FooProps) {
  const { bar } = props;
  // ^^^ Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of `this`.
  //     eslint(@typescript-eslint/unbound-method)
  return bar;
}
```

Answer (score 40):

This problem was infuriatingly easy to solve by simply replacing `bar(): void` with `bar: () => void`.

Example:

```js
interface FooProps {
  bar: () => void;
}

export function foo(props: FooProps) {
  const { bar } = props;  // no lint error
  return bar;
}
```

I'd always wondered why function-valued members of a TypeScript interface had two different syntaxes. I always assumed that both syntaxes had identical meanings. Now I know better: the `bar(): void` syntax apparently means "class member function" while `bar: () => void` means "function-valued property that doesn't use `this`".

*Leaving a Q&A pair here so the next victim won't waste a half hour like I did on this.*

Comment: I _wish_ I only wasted half an hour!

Comment: So at the end of the day, it all came down to syntax?? How dumb. I'm disabling this rule. Also I think your initial assumption about functions in interfaces was correct. I have not read anywhere that typescript makes any assumptions about the implementation of function types within interfaces. In my experience, interfaces just tell you the shape of the object, not how it will be implemented. Using the regular function syntax to declare the type of a function does not mean that "this" inside the function will always be associated with the object which contains that function

Comment: @Justin Grant. Thanks for making a Q&A pair.  Some people in SO don't realize that's one of the features of the platform.

Comment: This doesn't work with NextJS; it complains that the function is not serializable. I had to add `this: void` as a parameter instead

Answer (score 1):

The above will solve the eslint error, but if the function is used as a prop with NextJs/React, it will trigger an additional error:

> Props must be serializable for components in the "use client" entry file, "bar" is invalid.ts(71007)

In my case, the solution was

```
interface FooProps {
  bar(this: void): void;
}

export function foo(props: FooProps) {
  const { bar } = props;  // no lint error
  return bar;
}
```